# Ajax method doesn't fire controller Action method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Javascript/Jquery:

```
            specialInsDialog.dialog('open');

            specialInsDialog.find('#buttonSave').live('click', function () {

                function addSpecialInstuction(spinstructionVal, isYesVal) {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Portal/AddSpecialInstuction",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { providerKey: selProviderKey, ownerKey: selOwnerKey, petKey: selPetKey, instruction: spinstructionVal, isPermenant: isYesVal, invoiceId: selInvoiceId },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('sam');
                        }
                    });
                }

                var chkBox = document.getElementById('checkboxSpecialIns');

                if (chkBox.checked) {

                    var oTable = document.getElementById('table');
                    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;

                    for (i = 1; i < rowLength; i++) {

                        var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
                        var isYes = oCells[1].childNodes[0].checked;
                        var spinstruction = oCells[2].childNodes[0].value;

                        if (typeof (spinstruction) != 'undefined' && spinstruction != '') {

                            addSpecialInstuction(spinstruction, isYes);
                        }
                    }
                }
});
```

Controller :

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AddSpecialInstuction(string providerKey, string ownerKey, string petKey, string instruction, bool isPermenant, string invoiceId)
        {
            char[] delimiter = {'+'};
            string[] petKeys = petKey.Split(delimiter);
            Pet pet = null;  

            foreach (var key in petKeys)
            {
                pet = BasicRepository.GetPet(ownerKey, key);
                if (pet.SpecialInstructions != null && pet.SpecialInstructions.Where(a => a.Instruction.Trim() == instruction.Trim()).Count() <= 0)
                {
                    pet.AddSpecialInstruction(new SpecialInstruction()
                                                  {
                                                      Instruction = instruction,
                                                      IsPermenant = isPermenant,
                                                      PetId = pet.Id,
                                                      InvoiceId = isPermenant ? Guid.Empty : Guid.Parse(invoiceId)
                                                  });
                    BasicRepository.Save();
                }        
            } 
            Confirm("Your Special Instruction has been added.");
            return Json(string.Empty, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I am having above kind of code and `addSpecialInstuction` method only fires when I do run the code by using firebug.Without firebug controller Action method doesn't fire.

Note: Above ajax method is inside the jquery UI popup

So Why is that ?

Comment: Did you try to add an error handler in your ajax call to see if it's fired instead? Sometimes a mis-formatted JSON response can cause the request to fail.

Comment: @Mohamed Yes.I have put error handler.It's return 0.Why is that ?

Comment: why are you using the deprecated `live` method?

Comment: @DaveA I have changed it to on method.But result is the same.It doesn't make any impact for this problem.

Comment: So, to see if I understand, the event `click` handler always fires, but the `addSpecialInstuction` method only fires from firebug?

Comment: The signature of the jQuery error handler is Function(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown). What can you read in errorThrown?